# Kotlin parcelable and arrayList of parcelables

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I am trying to write a parcelable data object to pass to from **activityA** to **activityB** in my android application.

My object is passing with all the data, except my `arraylist` of the class Available Service

```
data class AvailableService(val id: Int,
                        val name: String,
                        val description: String,
                        val price: Double,
                        val currency: String,
                        val imageUrl: String) : Parcelable {

companion object {
    @JvmField @Suppress("unused")
    val CREATOR = createParcel { AvailableService(it) }
}

protected constructor(parcelIn: Parcel) : this(parcelIn.readInt(),
        parcelIn.readString(),
        parcelIn.readString(),
        parcelIn.readDouble(),
        parcelIn.readString(),
        parcelIn.readString())

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    dest?.writeInt(id)
    dest?.writeString(name)
    dest?.writeString(description)
    dest?.writeDouble(price)
    dest?.writeString(currency)
    dest?.writeString(imageUrl)
}

override fun describeContents() = 0
}
```

above is the available `serviceClass`, next I have Trip, which holds an `arraylist` of `AvailableService`.. I observed this in debug, it is successfully writing the `arraylist`, for some reason I have an issue with reading the data.

```
data class Trip(val id: String,
            val status: String,
            val orderedServices: ArrayList<OrderedService>) : Parcelable {

companion object {
    @JvmField @Suppress("unused")
    val CREATOR = createParcel { Trip(it) }
}

protected constructor(parcelIn: Parcel) : this(parcelIn.readString(),
        parcelIn.readString(),
        arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
            parcelIn.readArrayList(OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
        }
)

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    dest?.writeString(id)
    dest?.writeString(status)
    dest?.writeList(orderedServices)
}

override fun describeContents() = 0
}
```

in case someone wonders what's the fun of the CREATOR does, code below:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> createParcel(
    crossinline createFromParcel: (Parcel) -> T?): Parcelable.Creator<T> =
    object : Parcelable.Creator<T> {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): T? = createFromParcel(source)
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<out T?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
```

again, writing succeeds, but reading fails, I get an empty `arraylist`..
I think that part is the faulty one:

```
arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
        parcelIn.readArrayList(OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
    }
```

is there a different way to read/write `arraylist`? am I writing it wrong? reading it wrong?

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Replace:

```
arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
    parcelIn.readArrayList(OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

with:

```
arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
    parcelIn.readList(this, OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
    parcelIn.readArrayList(OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

to

```
source.createTypedArrayList(OrderedService.CREATOR)
```

Change `dest?.writeList(orderedServices)`

to `dest?.writeTypedList(orderedServices)`

The creator method

```
    companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Trip> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Trip> {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Trip = Trip(source)
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Trip?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Comment: no i have a crash with your solution (Error Unmarshalling unknown type code 55 at offset 13200), the first response is ok

Answer (score 6):

**For API 29 and above**

Replace:

```
arrayListOf<OrderedService>().apply {
    parcelIn.readArrayList(OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

with

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29)
    parcel.readParcelableList(this, OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
else
    parcel.readList(this as List<OrderedService>, OrderedService::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

and

```
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    dest?.writeString(id)
    dest?.writeString(status)
    dest?.writeList(orderedServices)
}
```

with

```
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    dest?.writeString(id)
    dest?.writeString(status)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        dest?.writeParcelableList(orderedServices,flags)
    } else {
        dest?.writeList(orderedServices as List<OrderedService>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If Parent and Child model have parcelable then used below one

**Parent Model**

```
Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.createTypedArrayList(ImagesModel.CREATOR)
    )
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeTypedList(images)
}
```